# Using bucket policy like firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this bucket policy that I use like firewall and expect that no one other than the 2 IP addresses should be able to download any file. But I am able to download a file from any IP address and not getting "permission denied" error.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3BucketPolicyFirewall",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "expected-network+athena",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-1aulyhwnmubu5-ap-south-1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-1aulyhwnmubu5-ap-south-1/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.241.233.31/32",
                        "1.2.5.1/32"
                    ]
                },
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:PrincipalIsAWSService": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I limit access to 2 IP addresses only irrespective of user's log-in status?

---

It is working as expected if I remove the line

"aws:PrincipalIsAWSService": "true"

But I need that so that Athena / redshift can access the data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag: QUESTIONS MUST BE ABOUT PROGRAMMING. Questions about general S3 support, functionality, configuration, etc. are OFF-TOPIC.

Comment: Why are you using a `DENY` policy? When you say that you can "download a file from any IP address", how are you downloading the file? If you are using the AWS CLI, then it is using permissions associated with your IAM User. There should be no need to `DENY` anything if you have correctly allocated `ALLOW` permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Your policy is saying:

- Deny access to this bucket
- If:

  - The Source IP is not one of these
  - AND the call to your resource is being made directly by an AWS service principal

The AND part is clearly causing your issue.

Please note that you should **avoid using `DENY` policies if possible**. Buckets are private by default, so you should control access by limiting who receives `ALLOW` permissions. The only time that `DENY` policies are appropriate is when you wish to override an `ALLOW` -- for example, if an Admin has access to *all buckets* but you wish to deny them access to a bucket that contains sensitive data.

In your case, rather than using a `DENY` to block access, simply change how you `ALLOW` access.

Comment: If you want to know the need of using "deny" effect, check the sid expected-network+athena+service-role from this official blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-makes-it-easier-to-manage-permissions-for-aws-services-accessing-resources/

Comment: redshift is not supported by "aws:CalledViaFirst" like athena and hence using "PrincipalIsAWSService"

Comment: Yes, but why do _you_ need to use a Deny policy in this instance? What IAM Role or IAM User has been granted access to the bucket that you now want to override and Deny? What is your actual goal for making this bucket policy?